# c++ Assertion failure on return from invariant function

Tags: c++, inheritance, invariants

I'm pretty new to C++ so please bear with me...

I'm writing a class that contains a **std::string** variable which I check if it is a valid C language identifier. 
*The valid identifiers start with "_" or a letter and continue with letters, numbers or _".* 
This class is used by the following classes NamedObject and Foo.

```
class Name{
    std::string name;
protected:
    virtual bool Inv(void) const{
            if (name[0] >= 'A' && name[0] <= 'Z') return true;
            if (name[0] >= 'a' && name[0] <= 'z') return true;
            if (name[0] == '_')                   return true;
            std::cout << "String input is not a valid identifier."<< std::endl;
            return false;
        }
public:
    Name(){}
    Name(std::string _name) : name(_name){ assert(Inv()); }
    Name(Name& n) : name(n.name) { assert(Inv()); }
    //more constructors and methods
};

class NamedObject{
    Name objectsName;
public:
    //Constructors & Destructor
    NamedObject()          : objectsName(Name()) {}
    NamedObject(Name name) : objectsName(name) {}
    ~NamedObject() {}

    //Accessors-Modifiers
    const Name& Get(void) const { return objectsName; }
    void        Set(const Name name) { objectsName = name; }
};

class Foo : public NamedObject {
public:
    Foo() : NamedObject() {}
    Foo(Name name) : NamedObject(name) {}
    ~Foo();
};
```

When I try the code:

```
Name n1("a_1");
Foo *f1 = new Foo(n1);
n1.Set("*a_2");
Foo *f2 = new Foo(n1);
```

I get the following error: 
Assertion failed: Inv() line 64 (line of second assert)
I have been trying to find the problem with Inv() but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Better use [`std::isalpha(char)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and its [siblings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte).

Comment: how does the code work?  "n1.Set("*a_2");"  class Name doesn't have method called Set.  That code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Name has Set and Get methods, I just didn't include them above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it assert-fails because your `"*a_2"` string is not a valid name (it doesn't begin with a letter or an underscore).

If you don't want to assert-fail, then either permit names to begin with an asterisk `"*"` as well, or use a name that begins with a letter or an underscore.

(By the way, as pointed out by Walter, you'd be much better off using `isalpha()` instead of the hacky, non-portable inequality checks against character codes.)

Comment: That solved my problem. I thought that in the case of a non-valid name the output would be printed and then the program would continue.

Comment: @NenaB I'm wondering what made you think that. You had the source code. You had read the documentation for `assert()`. I mean… did you?

Comment: I have read the documentation but apparently not very thoroughly since I was remembering it wrong... Next time I will search better before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
virtual bool Inv() const
{
  return std::isalpha(name[0]) || name[0] == '_';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way to do the checking!